# pass NSMutableArray from root view controller to pushed view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsmutablearray

i have 2 view controllers the first 1 is the root of uinavigationcontroller.
in that view controller (the first) i have nsmutable array that contains custom class that i created. so far so good :).

now in the second view controller (the child of the first) there is another nsmutable array
and i want to pass to him the array from the first view controller(from the root).

so in the method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

i used this code:

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailSegue"]){
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        tableViewController *controller = (tableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.monthnames = monthnames;
    }
```

but when i run the program and perform the segue i got this error message:

```
[tableViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9836f20
```

what am I'm doing wrong?

thanks to all helpers :)

Comment: please search many answers are already available on this forum

Comment: yea thats what i did i the last 2 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`segue.destinationViewController` is already your second view controller
(and not the navigation controller):

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailSegue"]){
     tableViewController *controller = (tableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
     controller.monthnames = monthnames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your segue point to table view controller not navigation controller. Replace your code to:

```
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailSegue"]){
        tableViewController *controller = (tableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.monthnames = monthnames;
    }
```

It should help.